# jquery Masonry items "collapsing" with fluid width option

Tags: jquery, jquery-masonry, masonry

I've written a jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/99gd6kt6/) that shows a jquery Masonry layout with static widths for the elements to be set in a "brick" layout. Seems to work just fine.

HTML:

```
<body>
<div id="container">
<div class="item">Ut condimentum mi vel tellus. Suspendisse laoreet. Fusce ut est sed dolor gravida convallis. Morbi vitae ante. Vivamus ultrices luctus nunc. Suspendisse et dolor. Etiam dignissim. Proin malesuada adipiscing lacus. Donec metus. Curabitur gravida.</div>
<div class="item">Donec nec justo eget felis facilisis fermentum. Aliquam porttitor mauris sit amet orci. Aenean dignissim pellentesque felis.</div>
<div class="item">Sed ac risus. Phasellus lacinia, magna a ullamcorper laoreet, lectus arcu pulvinar risus, vitae facilisis libero dolor a purus. Sed vel lacus. Mauris nibh felis, adipiscing varius, adipiscing in, lacinia vel, tellus. Suspendisse ac urna. Etiam pellentesque mauris ut lectus. Nunc tellus ante, mattis eget, gravida vitae, ultricies ac, leo. Integer leo pede, ornare a, lacinia eu, vulputate vel, nisl.</div>
<div class="item">Sed ac risus. Phasellus lacinia, magna a ullamcorper laoreet, lectus arcu pulvinar risus, vitae facilisis libero dolor a purus. Sed vel lacus. Mauris nibh felis, adipiscing varius, adipiscing in, lacinia vel, tellus. Suspendisse ac urna. Etiam pellentesque mauris ut lectus. Nunc tellus ante, mattis eget, gravida vitae, ultricies ac, leo. Integer leo pede, ornare a, lacinia eu, vulputate vel, nisl.</div>    
<div class="item">Phasellus pede arcu, dapibus eu, fermentum et, dapibus sed, urna.</div>
<div class="item">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Donec odio. Quisque volutpat mattis eros. Nullam malesuada erat ut turpis. Suspendisse urna nibh, viverra non, semper suscipit, posuere a, pede.</div>
</div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
#container {
    width: 900px;
}

.item {
    background: green;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px #fff; //to deliniate boxes
    float: left;
    width: 33.333%;
}
```

SCRIPT:

```
$('#container').masonry({
itemSelector: '.item',
columnWidth: 300
});
```

According to the [Masonry documentation](http://desandro.github.io/masonry/demos/fluid.html), you can pass in a function to set a non-static column width to a fraction of the container's width. I wrote another jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/cLcub3qa/), with the fluid width function replacing the static width function. The function is:

```
$('#container').masonry({
    itemSelector: '.item',
    columnWidth: function( containerWidth ) {
        return containerWidth / 3;
    }
});
```

As you can see, the .item divs "collapse" on one another since the masonry script positions them absolutely, but is not adding any top or left positioning styling as it does with the static column width version. I've tried this now dozens of times by using several masonry methods and loading script in various order, and I get the same result each time.

What am I missing here??

Comment: Your using  code for masonry v2 ( your link to documentation also is to v2) but using masonry v3 in your jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using the column width function, you can just use element sizing, per the documentation [here](http://masonry.desandro.com/options.html#element-sizing).

So instead of this:

```
$('#container').masonry({
    itemSelector: '.item',
    columnWidth: function( containerWidth ) {
        return containerWidth / 3;
    }
});
```

You can use this:

```
$('#container').masonry({
  itemSelector: '.item',
  columnWidth: '.item'
});
```

And then use a percentage width for .item in the css, i.e.

```
.item { width: 33.333%; }
```

[Here's the jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cLcub3qa/5/)